# How do i replace words with other words from string

Tags: php, string, function

I have strings which comes from my array like.

```
$a="Root|Electronics|Categories|Mobiles & Accessories|Smartphones & Basic Mobiles|Smartphones|";

$b="Root|Electronics|Categories|Mobiles & Accessories|Smartphones & Basic Mobiles|Smartphones & Mobiles";

$c="Root|Electronics|Categories|Mobiles & Accessories|Smartphones & Basic Mobiles|Smart Android mobile";
```

In the above example `Root|Electronics|Categories|Mobiles & Accessories|Smartphones & Basic Mobiles|` are common and the words in the string may change.

In this case I'm trying to find a common match from an array and this string replaces with a different string.

*For Example*: `Root|Electronics|Categories|Mobiles & Accessories|Smartphones & Basic Mobiles%` is the first common matched string, I would replace that with a different string like `Mobiles`.

To accomplish this, which php function could I use, or is there possibly some other way you could suggest?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you want to process, an array of strings or each string separately ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the common part you can use the function from here:

https://gist.github.com/chrisbloom7/1021218

You need to add your strings to an array and then use this code with example:

```
<?php
function longest_common_substring($words)
{
  $words = array_map('strtolower', array_map('trim', $words));
  $sort_by_strlen = create_function('$a, $b', 'if (strlen($a) == strlen($b)) { return strcmp($a, $b); } return (strlen($a) < strlen($b)) ? -1 : 1;');
  usort($words, $sort_by_strlen);
  // We have to assume that each string has something in common with the first
  // string (post sort), we just need to figure out what the longest common
  // string is. If any string DOES NOT have something in common with the first
  // string, return false.
  $longest_common_substring = array();
  $shortest_string = str_split(array_shift($words));
  while (sizeof($shortest_string)) {
    array_unshift($longest_common_substring, '');
    foreach ($shortest_string as $ci => $char) {
      foreach ($words as $wi => $word) {
        if (!strstr($word, $longest_common_substring[0] . $char)) {
          // No match
          break 2;
        } // if
      } // foreach
      // we found the current char in each word, so add it to the first longest_common_substring element,
      // then start checking again using the next char as well
      $longest_common_substring[0].= $char;
    } // foreach
    // We've finished looping through the entire shortest_string.
    // Remove the first char and start all over. Do this until there are no more
    // chars to search on.
    array_shift($shortest_string);
  }
  // If we made it here then we've run through everything
  usort($longest_common_substring, $sort_by_strlen);
  return array_pop($longest_common_substring);
}
```

Usage:

```
$array = array(
  'PTT757LP4',
  'PTT757A',
  'PCT757B',
  'PCT757LP4EV'
);
echo longest_common_substring($array);
// => T757
```